# How to replicate windows name sorting in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, windows-explorer, sorting

I need to print a list of files to a text document in the same order they show in the windows explorer alphabetic sort, but I can't find any method of sorting with `ls | sort` that shows the exact same order.

Files that start with brackets show first in the windows explorer, followed by numbers and then letters, but it always seems to order them ignoring the brackets every time I try.

Comment: `sort` and similar tools in Linux respect locale (`LC_COLLATE`). Any method that uses such tool and does not take locale into account is most likely flawed (i.e. it may work in one locale, not in some other). I have no idea if and how sorting in Windows depends on regional and language options. Theoretically the most elegant solution would be a locale that mimics Windows behavior (for certain Windows settings). Then you would just use `LC_COLLATE=… sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty way that i'll explain a little bit to help you get going:

I've made a few files with brackets, numbers and letters in their names in a test directory:

```
ls -la 
.
..
1.file
2.file
[1].file
[2].file
one.file
two.file
```

if I pipe ls to sort, they'll sort the same way.  What i can do, is first list only the files in the directory containing brackets (pipe ls to grep and look for [ specifically) and then write that to a file after sorting, and as a second step list the directory EXCLUDING all files with a bracket (grep -v) and then append that to the file previously created.  here im doing that in the parent directory to avoid having the file i created (list.txt) included in the results.

```
 ls | grep [[] | sort > ../list.txt && ls | grep -v [[] | sort >> ../list.txt; cat ../list.txt
[1].file
[2].file
1.file
2.file
one.file
two.file
```

I put the [ in brackets, because they need to be escaped or the shell will get cranky that you haven't closed them (and given the sort instructions it expects within the brackets).   depending on how complex a directory and file name structure you have this could be a quick and dirty one-liner fix.  If it's going to grow to be complex, look into SED and AWK.